# Multiple async requests simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

I'm trying to call ~ 300 API calls at the same time, so that I would get the results in a couple of seconds max.

My pseudo-code looks like this:

```
def function_1():
    colors = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue', + ~300 other ones]
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    res = loop.run_until_complete(get_color_info(colors))

async def get_color_info(colors):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    responses = []
    for color in colors:
        print("getting color")
        url = "https://api.com/{}/".format(color)
        data = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, url)
        r = await data
        responses.append(r.json())
    return responses
```

Doing this I get `getting color` printed out every second or so and the code takes forever, so I'm pretty sure they don't run simultaneously. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The ``await`` keyword literally means to *wait for* a result. Any instructions after it are only executed *after* the result is ready. Doing work concurrently requires running *several* coroutines at once, not having one do several things.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

#### `aiohttp` with Native Coroutines (`async`/`await`)

Here is a typical pattern that accomplishes what you're trying to do.  (Python 3.7+.)

One major change is that you will need to move from `requests`, which is built for synchronous IO, to a package such as [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) that is built specifically to work with `async`/`await` (native coroutines):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp  # pip install aiohttp aiodns


async def get(
    session: aiohttp.ClientSession,
    color: str,
    **kwargs
) -> dict:
    url = f"https://api.com/{color}/"
    print(f"Requesting {url}")
    resp = await session.request('GET', url=url, **kwargs)
    # Note that this may raise an exception for non-2xx responses
    # You can either handle that here, or pass the exception through
    data = await resp.json()
    print(f"Received data for {url}")
    return data


async def main(colors, **kwargs):
    # Asynchronous context manager.  Prefer this rather
    # than using a different session for each GET request
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for c in colors:
            tasks.append(get(session=session, color=c, **kwargs))
        # asyncio.gather() will wait on the entire task set to be
        # completed.  If you want to process results greedily as they come in,
        # loop over asyncio.as_completed()
        htmls = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        return htmls


if __name__ == '__main__':
    colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']  # ...
    # Either take colors from stdin or make some default here
    asyncio.run(main(colors))  # Python 3.7+
```

There are two distinct elements to this, one being the asynchronous aspect of the coroutines and one being the concurrency introduced on top of that when you specify a container of tasks (futures):

- You create one coroutine `get` that uses `await` with two *awaitables*: the first being [`.request`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/49261c192ff225372dffb39056c3c311714b12c5/aiohttp/client.py#L245) and the second being [`.json`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/49261c192ff225372dffb39056c3c311714b12c5/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py#L985).  This is the async aspect.  The purpose of `await`ing these IO-bound responses is to tell the event loop that other `get()` calls can take turns running through that same routine.
- The concurrent aspect is encapsulated in `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`.  This maps the awaitable `get()` call to each of your `colors`.  The result is an aggregate list of returned values.  Note that this wrapper will wait until *all* of your responses come in and call `.json()`.  If, alternatively, you want to process them greedily as they are ready, you can loop over [`asyncio.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed): each Future object returned represents the earliest result from the set of the remaining awaitables.

Lastly, take note that [`asyncio.run()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fec35c99aa749bb90cb29349bed6b3393907c4c1/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L8) is a high-level "porcelain" function introduced in Python 3.7.  In earlier versions, you can mimic it (roughly) like:

```
# The "full" versions makes a new event loop and calls
# loop.shutdown_asyncgens(), see link above
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main(colors))
finally:
    loop.close()
```

---

#### Limiting Requests

There are a number of ways to limit the rate of concurrency.  For instance, see [`asyncio.semaphore` in async-await function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40845135/7954504) or [large numbers of tasks with limited concurrency](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2017/05/31/python-3-large-numbers-of-tasks-with-limited-concurrency/).

Comment: Good answer. I wish there was a blog post that explained this as succinctly. Introductory texts on the topic are often outdated or downright incorrect. You might want to mention the use of `Semaphore` to limit the number of concurrent requests, which tends to belong to the same pattern.

Comment: @user4815162342 Here's an article I wrote recently - appreciate any feedback & corrections.  https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

Comment: when i tried this, it till did everything in series (i.e. make call and get response _for that call_ immediately) until i put `asyncio.sleep(0)` after the `get`.  is this necessary?

Comment: Great article and answer, @BradSolomon!
Have there been any updates since 2019?

Answer (score 2):

This code below can run **`test()` 10 times concurrently and asynchronously** printing the numbers from `0` to `99`:

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    for i in range(0, 100):
        print(i)

async def call_tests():
    tasks = []

    for _ in range(0, 10):
        tasks.append(test())

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(call_tests())
```

And, this code below is **the shorthand `for` loop version** of the above code running **`test()` 10 times asynchronously** printing the numbers from `0` to `99`:

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    [print(i) for i in range(0, 100)]

async def call_tests():
    tasks = [test() for _ in range(0, 10)]

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(call_tests())
```

This is the result below:

```
...
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
```