# Concurrent HTTP and SQL requests using async Python 3

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

first time trying `asyncio` and `aiohttp`.
I have the following code that gets `urls` from the `MySQL` database for `GET` requests. Gets the responses and pushes them to `MySQL` database.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    database_name = 'db_name'
    company_name = 'company_name'

    my_db = Db(database=database_name) # wrapper class for mysql.connector
    urls_dict = my_db.get_rest_api_urls_for_specific_company(company_name=company_name)
    update_id = my_db.get_updateid()
    my_db.get_connection(dictionary=True)

    for url in urls_dict:
        url_id = url['id']
        url = url['url']
        table_name = my_db.make_sql_table_name_by_url(url)
        insert_query = my_db.get_sql_for_insert(table_name)
        r = requests.get(url=url).json() # make the request
        args = [json.dumps(r), update_id, url_id]
        my_db.db_execute_one(insert_query, args, close_conn=False)

    my_db.close_conn()
```

This works fine but to speed it up How can I run it `asynchronously`?

I have looked [here](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021448/multiple-async-requests-simultaneously) and [here](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2019/02/26/python-async-basics-video-100-million-http-requests/) but can't seem to get my head around it.

Here is what I have tried based on @Raphael Medaer's answer.

```py
async def fetch(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.request(method='GET', url=url) as response:
            json = await response.json()
            return json


async def process(url, update_id):
    table_name = await db.make_sql_table_name_by_url(url)
    result = await fetch(url)
    print(url, result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Get urls from DB"""
    db = Db(database="fuse_src")
    urls = db.get_rest_api_urls()  # This returns list of dictionary
    update_id = db.get_updateid()
    url_list = []
    for url in urls:
        url_list.append(url['url'])
    print(update_id)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(*[process(url, update_id) for url in url_list]))
```

I get an error in the `process` method:

```py
TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Not sure whats the problem?

Any code example specific to this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `commit` all queries and `execute` only once.

Comment: thanks @Frank any code `fragments` would be appreciated?

Comment: Sorry I really forget how to do it. I had the same problem before, I just remembered what I did is append all the queries and send to server all at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make this code *asynchronous* will not speed it up at all. Except if you consider to run a part of your code in "parallel". For instance you can run multiple (SQL or HTTP) queries in "same time". By doing asynchronous programming you will not execute code in "same time". Although you will get benefit of long IO tasks to execute other part of your code while you're waiting for IOs.

First of all, you'll have to use *asynchronous* libraries (instead of *synchronous* one).

- `mysql.connector` could be replaced by [aiomysql](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql) from aio-libs.
- `requests` could be replaced by [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/)

To execute multiple asynchronous tasks in "parallel" (for instance to replace your loop `for url in urls_dict:`), you have to read carefully about [asyncio tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) and function [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather).

I will not (re)write your code in an asynchronous way, however here are a few lines of pseudo code which could help you:

```py
async def process(url):
    result = await fetch(url)
    await db.commit(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = MyDbConnection()
    urls = await db.fetch_all_urls()

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(*[process(url) for url in urls]))
```

Comment: This is super helpful. Will try and report back. thanks @Raphael Medaer :)

Comment: I have good success as far as getting url results but stumped on db side :(

Comment: I saw your edit with the error. However without the full stacktrace we cannot help you. Could you also put the code of `db.make_sql_table_name_by_url(url)` and [write a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: The above error was due to the fact that `db.make_sql_table_name_by_url(url)` method wasn't `async` lol. I fixed it and it works fine. The problem I have now is if the `db.make_sql_table_name_by_url(url)` is in the same file, it works. But if I create a wrapper class out of it. It gives `AttributeError: module 'asyncio.streams' has no attribute 'IncompleteReadError'`

Comment: OK. I guess we can consider that off topic or as another question. I hope my answer helped you to get a better idea of the big picture. Could you give a full working example once it's done ? And optionally accept the answer ? Kind regards,