# Very slow http post requests in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, facebook-chatbot

I have created a python script which collects json data from facebook graph api and check for user job_title information.

By using this script, I am notifying users to update their job_title via chatbot but this process takes too much time to send requests to all users.

```
import json
import requests

users_url = Facebook API to fetch user details
MESSAGE_TO_SEND = '....PLEASE UPDATE JOB TITLE....'

ACCESS_TOKEN = Page_Access_token

def reply(user_id, msg,ACCESS_TOKEN):
    data = {
        "recipient": { "id": user_id },
        "message": { "text": msg }
    }

    resp = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/messages?access_token="+ ACCESS_TOKEN, json=data)
    print('Message Sent to : ',user_id)
    # print(resp.content, resp, 'response from facebook')

def header(ACCESS_TOKEN):
    return {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN}

def user_data(ACCESS_TOKEN):
    
    headers = header(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    data = requests.get(users_url,headers=headers)
    result_json = json.loads(data.text)
    resources = result_json['Resources']
    
    for titles in range(0,len(resources)):
            if 'title' not in resources[titles]:
                user_id = str(resources[titles]['id'])
                reply(user_id, MESSAGE_TO_SEND,ACCESS_TOKEN)


user_data(ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

Please Help me....What can i do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You could try spawning multiple threads. How long is `resources`? `requests.post` is a blocking call but most of that is the thread doing nothing, waiting for the request to go out over the wire and the response to come back. The process could be processing other requests instead of sitting on its hands.

Comment: @ggorlen its approx 10000-20000

Comment: Thanks. How much  time are you expecting 10k+ requests to take, roughly? How long is this taking currently on your machine?

Comment: @ggorlen It's taking approx 1 second for sending 1 notification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple async requests simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021448/multiple-async-requests-simultaneously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/concurrency_in_python/concurrency_in_python_pool_of_threads.htm)...

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
import time

def square(n):
    time.sleep(3.0)
    print( n * n )

def main():
    values = range(10)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 5) as executor:
        results = executor.map(square, values)
    # for result in results:
        # print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = time.time()
    main()
    et = time.time()
    print('{:.3f} seconds'.format(et-st))
```

Replace `values` with your list of user_ids and `square` with your `reply` function and set `max_workers` to a number of your liking.